# Trigger MySQL increment if field is already present

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to increment a field when I insert a new row which is nearly identical than another (the only difference is `id_progress`). For much clarity I will use this sample

```
+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
| id_progress | task_id | case_id | loop_nb |
+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
|         800 | 2001002 |     199 | null    |
|         801 | 2001003 |     199 | null    |
|         802 | 2002001 |     199 | null    |
|         803 | 2002002 |     199 | null    |
|         804 | 2001002 |     200 | null    |
|         805 | 2001002 |     199 | 1       |
|         806 | 2001002 |     199 | 2       |
+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I want to increment the `loop_nb` of a new row if `task_id` and `case_id` are already present in another row.

In this exemple, row `805` was added after row `804`. Knowing that `805` is nearly the same than `800`, the trigger increment the loop_nb before insert in the database.

I tried something, I am pretty new to trigger so sorry id I did it wrong

```
BEGIN
 DECLARE loop_nb integer;
 SET @loop_nb := (select loop_nb
     from progress 
     where task_id = NEW.task_id 
     AND case_id = NEW.case_id
     DESC LIMIT 1 );
 IF ISNULL(@loop_nb) THEN
     SET @loop_nb := @loop_nb+1;
 END IF;
 SET NEW.loop_nb = @loop_nb;
 END
```

But the problem is that my `loop_nb` is `null` by default. And I do not think I have the permission to change it.

Is there any alternatives?
Should my code be ok if I could change the default values of loop_nb to `'0'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a code like the following can help, at least, gives you some ideas.

```sql
mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trg_bi_progress`//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `progress`//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `progress` (
    ->   `id_progress` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `task_id` VARCHAR(7),
    ->   `case_id` INT UNSIGNED,
    ->   `loop_nb` INT UNSIGNED
    -> )//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `trg_bi_progress` BEFORE INSERT ON `progress`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SET NEW.`loop_nb` := (
    ->       SELECT NULLIF(COUNT(`id_progress`), 0)
    ->       FROM `progress`
    ->       WHERE `task_id` = NEW.`task_id`
    ->       AND `case_id` = NEW.`case_id`
    ->     );
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `progress` (`task_id`, `case_id`)
    -> VALUES
    -> ('2001002', 199),
    -> ('2001003', 199),
    -> ('2002001', 199),
    -> ('2002002', 199),
    -> ('2001002', 200),
    -> ('2001002', 199),
    -> ('2001002', 199)//
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `id_progress`,
    ->   `task_id`,
    ->   `case_id`,
    ->   `loop_nb`
    -> FROM
    ->   `progress`;
+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
| id_progress | task_id | case_id | loop_nb |
+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
|           1 | 2001002 |     199 |    NULL |
|           2 | 2001003 |     199 |    NULL |
|           3 | 2002001 |     199 |    NULL |
|           4 | 2002002 |     199 |    NULL |
|           5 | 2001002 |     200 |    NULL |
|           6 | 2001002 |     199 |       1 |
|           7 | 2001002 |     199 |       2 |
+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```